# Android SearchView: startActivity() gets called twice

Tags: android, search, searchview, start-activity

The architecture is the following:
 1) MainActionBarActivity - base class, which implements the ActionBar behavior, i.e. overriding onCreateOptionsMenu(), onOptionsItemSelected(), onSearchRequested() and **startActivity()** 
 2) HomeActivity extends MainActionBarActivity
 3) SearchableActivity extends MainActionBarActivity

For some reason, when typing in the search box in HomeActivity and hit Enter, **startActivity()** gets called twice and therefore 2 intents arrive at SearchableActivity (debug messages in LogCat)
 Could you give me some directions where the problem might be?

Comment: the problem is in your code you didn't post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As SearchableActivity was set with `launchMode="singleTop"` I had to override `onNewIntent()`. 
 The problem was solvled by removing `super.onNewIntent()`.